# xslt sorting for some part of a file

Tags: sorting, xslt

I'm very new to XSLT, and I want to sort a part of XML file.(keeping all the file data)

Here's the file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">

  <SchemaVersion>1.0</SchemaVersion>

  <Header>### uVision Project, (C) Keil Software</Header>

  <Extensions>
    <cExt>*.c</cExt>
    <aExt>*.s*; *.src; *.a*</aExt>
    <oExt>*.obj</oExt>
    <lExt>*.lib</lExt>
    <tExt>*.txt; *.h; *.inc</tExt>
    <pExt>*.plm</pExt>
    <CppX>*.cpp</CppX>
    <nMigrate>0</nMigrate>
  </Extensions>

  <DateTime>
    <dwLowDateTime>0</dwLowDateTime>
    <dwHighDateTime>0</dwHighDateTime>
  </DateTime>

  <Target>
    <TargetName>LYNX_XERIUS_APRR_CPU2006_0091</TargetName>
    <ToolsetNumber>0x4</ToolsetNumber>
    <TargetOption>
      <OPTTT>
        <gFlags>0</gFlags>
      </OPTTT>
      <AAA>
        <SetRegEntry>
          <Number>0</Number>
        </SetRegEntry>
      </AAA>
      <Breakpoint>
        <Bp>
          <Number>0</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>1</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>2</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>3</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>4</Number>
        </Bp>
      </Breakpoint>
      <Tracepoint>
        <THDelay>0</THDelay>
      </Tracepoint>
      <DebugFlag>
        <trace>0</trace>
      </DebugFlag>
      <LintExecutable></LintExecutable>
    </TargetOption>
  </Target>


  <Target>
    <TargetName>Debug</TargetName>
    <ToolsetNumber>0x4</ToolsetNumber>
    <TargetOption>
      <OPTTT>
        <gFlags>0</gFlags>
      </OPTTT>
      <AAA>
        <SetRegEntry>
          <Number>0</Number>
        </SetRegEntry>
      </AAA>
      <Breakpoint>
        <Bp>
          <Number>0</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>1</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>2</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>3</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>4</Number>
        </Bp>
      </Breakpoint>
      <Tracepoint>
        <THDelay>0</THDelay>
      </Tracepoint>
      <DebugFlag>
        <trace>0</trace>
      </DebugFlag>
      <LintExecutable></LintExecutable>
    </TargetOption>
  </Target>


  <Target>
    <TargetName>LYNX_HERMES_APRR_SERIE_200</TargetName>
    <ToolsetNumber>0x4</ToolsetNumber>
    <TargetOption>
      <OPTTT>
        <gFlags>0</gFlags>
      </OPTTT>
      <AAA>
        <SetRegEntry>
          <Number>0</Number>
        </SetRegEntry>
      </AAA>
      <Breakpoint>
        <Bp>
          <Number>0</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>1</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>2</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>3</Number>
        </Bp>
        <Bp>
          <Number>4</Number>
        </Bp>
      </Breakpoint>
      <Tracepoint>
        <THDelay>0</THDelay>
      </Tracepoint>
      <DebugFlag>
        <trace>0</trace>
      </DebugFlag>
      <LintExecutable></LintExecutable>
    </TargetOption>
  </Target>  
  <Group>
    <GroupName>::CMSIS</GroupName>
    <tvExp>0</tvExp>
    <tvExpOptDlg>0</tvExpOptDlg>
    <cbSel>0</cbSel>
    <RteFlg>1</RteFlg>
  </Group>

</Project>
```

Here's my XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns="urn:TestNamespace"                >
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[not(string-length(normalize-space()))]"/>

  <xsl:template match="Project">
    <xsl:copy>    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Target">    
        <xsl:sort select="TargetName"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- global template to copy everything that doesn't match the other templates -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got a XML file sorted by **TargetName** as output, but with only **Target nodes**....

How can I setup the select case to keep the unfiltered nodes ?

I also tested with :

```
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Target">    
    <xsl:sort select="TargetName"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
```

In this case, all data is kept but there is **no sorting** ?

I will appreciate some explanation to improve my knowledge.

Best Regards

Comment: You haven't said anything about the range of input files that the stylesheet might need to handle. Might there be other children of the Project element? Will all the Target children always be adjacent? What should happen if they aren't adjacent?

Comment: You also haven't said whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Since 2.0 solutions are often much easier, but many people are still using 1.0, it's important to know.

Comment: In fact most example I found where 1.0.....
The data sample I put on the site is not correct.
All   <Target><TargetName></TargetName></Target> are chlidren of <Targets> node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One approach is:*

```
<xsl:template match="Project">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
            <xsl:sort select="TargetName" />                
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

*Why is your solution not working:*

> `<xsl:apply-templates select="Target">`

You select only `Target` to apply further.

Comment: Please have a look at: http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVm; The element `target` is sorted by the child `TargetName` asc. Order is: "Debug", "LYNX_HERMES_APRR_SERIE_200", "LYNX_XERIUS_APRR_CPU2006_0091".

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry, that effectively works with this data.
In fact I test with the full file which is bigger, and which doesn't work.
Now I have to understand why that works with the less lines....
Thank you .

Comment: Ok I found the difference : with my actual data there is another node level

<Targets>
<Target>
<TargetName>X</TargetName>
</Target>
<Target>
<TargetName>D</TargetName>
</Target>
<Target>
<TargetName>L</TargetName>
</Target>
</Targets>

Comment: So I changed 
<xsl:template match="Project"> to <xsl:template match="Targets"> and it works fine

Comment: All right, seems like you got the "concept" of sorting in xslt. Feel free to upvote and close your question by mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this (using XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:template match="Project">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="node-name()">
         <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="TargetName"/>             
         </xsl:apply-templates>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

on the assumption that sorting groups of elements other than Target elements does no harm. But it would probably be cleaner to have a conditional (`xsl:choose`) inside the `xsl:for-each-group` so the sorting is only done when `test="self::Target"`.

Comment: I'v got the  error : 'xsl:for-each-group' coul not be child of 'xsl:copy'. with V1.0

Comment: With V2.0 . 'for-each-group' is not a recognized extension element.

Comment: As I made clear, you need an XSLT 2.0 processor to run this. (Saying version="2.0" in your stylesheet doesn't magically convert your ancient XSLT 1.0 processor into a sparkling new XSLT 2.0 processor).